# How to calculate sums across matrix diagonals in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say, I have matrix `4x4` like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
4 3 2 1
8 7 6 5`
```

I want to get matrix `2*4-1` with elements like:

```
8
4+7
5+3+6
1+6+2+5
2+7+1
3+8
4
```

How can I do that in Tensorflow? With tensors, of course - I have tensor with shape `[a,b,c,..,l,n,n]` and want to get tensor with shape `[a,b,c,...,l,2*n-1]`. Is there any single function to do this or looping is the only way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tf.py_func` to wrap a `numpy` function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def np_all_trace_sum(a):
    n = a.shape[-1]
    all_trace_sum = [a.trace(i,axis1=-1,axis2=-2) for i in range(n-1,-n,-1)] # shape = (2*n-1,a,b,c,..,l)
    return np.moveaxis(all_trace_sum,0,-1) # shape = (a,b,c,..,l,2*n-1)

A = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,None,4,4],dtype=tf.float32)
result = tf.py_func(np_all_trace_sum, [A], tf.float32)

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[4,3,2,1],[8,7,6,5]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result,feed_dict={A:[[a,a,a],[a,a,a]]}))

[[[ 8. 11. 14. 14. 10. 11.  4.]
  [ 8. 11. 14. 14. 10. 11.  4.]
  [ 8. 11. 14. 14. 10. 11.  4.]]

 [[ 8. 11. 14. 14. 10. 11.  4.]
  [ 8. 11. 14. 14. 10. 11.  4.]
  [ 8. 11. 14. 14. 10. 11.  4.]]]
```